# Sports match MySQL query join match and teams in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'd like to create a database for sport matches.

A team can have 0 or 1 match. A match has always 2 teams.

Example data I have to store:

- Match **start time**
- **Team name** for A and B
- **Score** for A and B

I thought about creating a table for **match** and a table for **team**. Match has got the start time and foreign keys of A and B. Team has got the name and score.

**Now my question/problem:**

I'd like to search a team name and receive a table like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Start | SearchedName | SearchedScore | OpponentName | OpponentScore
 ...  | ...          | ...           | ...          | ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically join the `team` table twice.

Assuming the following table structure:

```
table: "matches"
    id_team_a
    id_team_b
    start_time
    ...

table: "teams"
    id_team
    name
```

You would go:

```
select 
    m.*,
    ta.name team_name_a,
    tb.name team_name_b
from matches m
inner join teams ta on ta.id_team = m.id_team_a
inner join teams tb on tb.id_team = m.id_team_b
```

---

If you want to handle that with a search:

```
select 
    m.*,
    case when ta.name = @myteam then ta.name else tb.name end search_name,
    case when ta.name = @myteam then tb.name else ta.name end opponent_name
from matches m
inner join teams ta on ta.id_team = m.id_team_a
inner join teams tb on tb.id_team = m.id_team_b
where @myteam in (ta.name, tb.name)
```